# Audio Player in NativeScript-Vue

Tags: vue.js, audio, vuejs2, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have an mp3 playlist and I want to play these audio tracks in an audio player in `NativeScript-Vue`. However, there is no plugin for it.

However, there is a NativeScript plugin `nativescript-audio` which can be used for playing audio.

In the following Playground example, you will notice that it has been adopted to play in a NativeScript-Vue application.

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=83Hs3D&v=19

This can work, however, the problem is that the player is mounted in the `mounted()` hook, and even the mp3 file path is supplied there. However, for me, the mp3 file is loaded asynchronously, added to a Vuex store, and then available as computed property in the component.

How can I adopt this code to take the mp3 file from a computed property rather than hard-coded in `mounted()`?

Here is the documentation for this plugin - https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-audio

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution.

1. Watch your computed property. Let's say it's called `media`.
2. On change, update the audio track using the following code:

   const playerOptions = {
         audioFile: this.media,
         loop: false,
         autoplay: false
     }
     this._player
       .playFromUrl(playerOptions)
       .then(function(res) {
         console.log(res);
       })
       .catch(function(err) {
         console.log('something went wrong..', err);
       });